# how to give a struct * as argument to a function

Tags: c

I want to pass alloc as an argument but don't know how, can somebody help me?

```
void parameter(unsigned int argnum, struct resistor* alloc)
{
/*...*/
}

struct resistort
{
  const double E6[6];
  double E12[12];
  const double E24[24];
  char e[3];
  double value;
  double log10val;
  double val;
  double serielval[2];
  double reset;
}rv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct resistor *alloc = NULL;
  alloc = (struct resistor *)malloc(sizeof(struct resistor));

  parameter(argc, alloc);
}
```

in parameter I want to free(alloc)

I have hoped that it would function this way:

```
void parameter(unsigned int argnum, struct resistor* alloc);
```

but then I get this

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'parameter' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
note: expected 'struct resistor *' but argument is of type 'struct resistor *'
error: conflicting types for 'parameter'
```

Comment: Where is `struct resistor` defined? Where is the `parameter` function declared? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please include a copy-paste of the *full* and *complete* output when building (what you show is just a smaller note of a larger message). And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/hSNd3P).

Comment: Don't you get any warnings? If I run this in compiler explorer, I get warning `"warning: 'struct resistor' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration"`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Your definition of the struct is before the function `parameter`

Comment: `struct resistort` must be `struct resistor` ?

Comment: You forgot to show us the other 2 warnings...

Comment: Are you saying that `struct resistor` is defined *after* the function that is supposed to use it? If we copy and paste the code you show, *as you show it*, will we get the exact same errors you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting warning `incompatible pointer type` because you are using `struct resistor` before declaration:

```
void parameter(unsigned int argnum, struct resistor* alloc)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In your program, the declaration of `struct resistor` is after `parameter()` function.
You can solve this problem by either moving the `struct resistor` declaration before function `parameter()` or just do the forward declaration of `struct resistor` before `parameter()` function, like this:

```
struct resistor; //forward declaration 

void parameter(unsigned int argnum, struct resistor* alloc)
{
/*...*/
}

struct resistor
{
    const double E6[6];
    double E12[12];
    const double E24[24];
    char e[3];
    double value;
    double log10val;
    double val;
    double serielval[2];
    double reset;
}rv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct resistor *alloc = NULL;
    alloc = (struct resistor *)malloc(sizeof(struct resistor));

    parameter(argc, alloc);
}
```